# How to enumerate running ec2 instances and load them into a database using ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using aws-sdk gem, I can't figure how to list all the running ec2 instances and load them to a database.

I need an approach on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above will return all instances, not just running instances. You can use a filter to get only running instances:

```
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new
ec2.instances.filter('instance-state-name', 'running')
```

Comment: Does this deal with pagination ?

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(
    access_key_id: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    secret_access_key: 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    region: 'YOUR_EC2_REGION'
)

ec2.instances
```

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html

Comment: this solution gives all the instances, even the ones that are not running. The solution from @luke_Chadwick works fine. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Install the AWS ClI and run the following to get a list of running instance ids:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
| grep InstanceId | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/^\"//g' | sed 's/\",$//g'
```