# Auth and get running instance count for azure in ruby

Tags: ruby, azure

How can I get the running instance count for Azure in ruby, I'm looking something equivalent to [How to enumerate running ec2 instances and load them into a database using ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668315/how-to-enumerate-running-ec2-instances-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ruby) in AWS.

Thanks

Here is what I did:

```
subscription_id= 'xyz' 
provider = MsRestAzure::ApplicationTokenProvider.new(tenant_id, client_id, secret)
  credentials = MsRest::TokenCredentials.new(provider)
  client = Azure::ARM::Resources::ResourceManagementClient.new(credentials)
  client.subscription_id = subscription_id
  resource_group_params = Azure::ARM::Resources::Models::ResourceGroup.new()
  resource_group_params.location = 'westus'
  promise = client.resource_groups.create_or_update('new_test_resource_group',resource_group_params)
  result = promise.value!
  resource_group_params = result.body
  p resource_group_params.name 
  p resource_group_params.id
```

Response:

azureAuth.rb:35:in `<main>': undefined method`value!' for # (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, it is hard to know this "running instance". Do you mean Azure web app or Azure cloud service instance? Based on your code snippet, you seem want to create Azure resource group and get some related info. For this scenario, I suggest you follow the sample code in Azure official site: [Manage Azure resources and resource groups with Ruby](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/resource-manager-ruby-resources-and-groups/#create-group). Hope it could give you some tips.

#### [Update]

I am sorry for that I did not test the sample code and give solution to you.

> still it is throwing error "nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Based on my test, I think you did not create azure resource group, so the promise object is nil. Please try list resource group operation `client.resource_groups.list.each{ |group| print_item(group) }` I think you will get nil issue too. When I dig into the `ms_rest_azure` I could not even able to get token. When I change below code (application_token_provider.rb)  I could able to get the token

1) `request_body['{resource_uri}'] = "https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F" #ERB::Util.url_encode(@settings.token_audience)`. Use management.azure.com instead of management.core.windows.net

2) `response = connection.post do |request|` get method change to post method.

3) `:ssl => MsRest.ssl_options` change to `:ssl => {:verify => false}`

I would suggest you use rest API to achieve the same purpose. Below is my Ruby code based on rest API. Hope it helps.

```
  connection = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://login.windows.net/<telnet id>/oauth2/token',:ssl => {:verify => false}) do |builder|
    builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
 end
 response = connection.post do |request|
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    request.body = 'resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F&client_id=<your client id>&client_secret=<your client secret>&grant_type=client_credentials'
 end 
  response_body = JSON.load(response.body)
  @token = response_body['access_token']
  getResrouceCon = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriotion id>/resourcegroups?api-version=2015-01-01',:ssl => {:verify => false}) do |builder|     
    builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
 end
 response_resource = getResrouceCon.get do |req|
     req.headers["Authorization"] = "bearer #{@token}"
 end
 puts "response #{response_resource.body}"
```

Note: I use the latest version `azure_mgmt_resource`

#### [Update]

We could find Azure classic cloud service from [Azure resource portal](https://resources.azure.com/). we can get a lot of useful info of Azure cloud service from configuration. here is the screenshot:

[image]

If you want to get roles and role instance. We can use this rest API in Azure resource portal `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/<cloud service name>/slots/Production?api-version=2016-04-01`

We only need to modify a little from my previous answer. Here is the code that could get cloud service configuration:

```
 getResrouceCon = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/<cloud service name>/slots/Production?api-version=2016-04-01',:ssl => {:verify => false}) do |builder|     
    builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
 end
 response_resource = getResrouceCon.get do |req|
     req.headers["Authorization"] = "bearer #{@token}"
 end
 puts "response #{response_resource.body}"
```